# ng-repeat doesn't work when parent's css is set to display: none

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div with a class the css of which is `display: none;`. Upon a button click I change the class with a class toggle `ng-class="vm.showing ? 'zoomIn' : 'zoomOut'"`. The problem is that angular doesn't seem to populate the ng-repeat element when the style is set to `display: none;`.

**Edit** I want to use animate.css, so actually the code would be `ng-class="vm.showing ? 'zoomIn' : 'zoomOut'`

Updated code:

```
<button ng-click="vm.showing = true" type="button">View Panel</button>

<div ng-class="vm.showing ? 'zoomIn' : 'zoomOut'">
    <button ng-click="vm.showing = false" type="button">Close Panel</button>
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Old code - disregard**

```
<button ng-click="vm.showing = true" type="button">View Panel</button>

<div ng-class="vm.showing ? '' : 'display-none'">
    <button ng-click="vm.showing = false" type="button">Close Panel</button>
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make this work properly so that the ng-repeat directive populates the repeated element?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense, unless part of your `zoomIn` or `zoomOut` class is using `display: none;`.  And if the div is indeed set to `display: none;` then it would be normal and accepted for the repeat nested inside to not be populated;  why would you want to populate a dom tree that isn't visible?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I made a plunkr and it was working fine, then opened dev tools on actual code I'm working on, it was a dupes error in angular

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides a `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives that you should use instead of display: none:

```
<div ng-show="vm.showing">
<button ng-click="vm.showing = false" type="button">Close Panel</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
    ...
</div>
```

Ng-show gives you a much cleaner syntax so it's worth using just for that.

My guess is that the traditional `display: none` method doesn't work because of performance optimisations. You're telling Angular that there's no need to render that block because it's hidden. You then make it visible, but because it's happening in CSS Angular doesn't know that it needs to update.

[Quick tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-click="vm.showing = true" type="button">View Panel</button>

<div ng-show="vm.showing">
    <button ng-click="vm.showing = false" type="button">Close Panel</button>
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Now Use animate.css